# How can I prevent access to specific path with ServiceStack Authentication?

Tags: servicestack

When we want to prevent access to specific path with default asp.net authentication, we do:

```
<location path="routes.axd">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Agent"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

How can we do with ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration to protect /paths in ServiceStack.

### Using the [Authenticate] Attribute

You can protect services by adding the `[Authenticate]` attribute on either the Action:

```
class MyService : Service {
    [Authenticate] 
    public object Get(Protected request) { ... }
}
```

The Request DTO

```
[Authenticate] 
class Protected { ... }
```

Or the service implementation

```
[Authenticate] 
class MyService : Service {
    public object Get(Protected request) { ... }
}
```

Or by inheriting from a base class

```
[Authenticate] 
class MyServiceBase : Service { ... }


class MyService : MyServiceBase {
    public object Get(Protected request) { ... }
}
```

### Using a Global Request Filter

Otherwise if you can use a [global Request Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) if you wanted to restrict all requests any other way, e.g something like:

```
appHost.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
{
    if (IsAProtectedPath(httpReq.PathInfo)) {
       new AuthenticateAttribute()
         .Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's ok for services. But for classical requests (not XHR) it does not work?

Comment: Also Elmah can handle Exception in Actions but could not handle exceptions in Services..

Comment: A ServiceStack Page Request? All ServiceStack handled Web Requests go through the Global Request Filters

Comment: Hmm. I think there is a conflict with other frameworks that I'm using.. Elmah and AttributeRouting. I'm setting your answer as accepted but problem is going on for me..

Comment: It's important to put as much of your context in your question. If you're not talking about calls to ServiceStack web services, than this question has nothing to do with ServiceStack and you should be labeling it with ASP.NET family* tags.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17837/discussion-between-ozz-and-mythz)

Comment: I am having this issue when requesting pages, also.  I've described the behaviour in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304736/servicestack-global-request-filter-not-firing